# Stopping Verizon from installing apps on your phone without consent?

Tags: applications, permissions

I recently switched cell phone providers from T-Mobile to Verizon. The next day, I noticed a ton of crappy apps, mostly dumb games, were installed on my phone, a Samsung Galaxy S22.

As I already have a lot of problems with bloatware, I uninstalled these apps, and want to ensure that Verizon doesn't install anything else without permission. The idea of a big creepy corporation installing unknown things on my cell phone is unnerving.

My phone's not jailbroken. However, a lot of [guides](https://techshift.net/how-do-i-stop-verizon-app-manager-from-downloading-apps/) suggest uninstalling the app called "Verizon App Manager", but I didn't even have an app called "Verizon App Manager", just "Verizon Services". Then I uninstalled all the app's updates, and viola, its name reverted to "Verizon App Manager". However, the app can't be uninstalled.

I removed all of its permissions, but as Verizon was able to install this app without permission, I doubt how long that will work.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a broad answer. You can uninstall system apps from adb. search for "pm uninstall" you will find a lot of answers.

However, something to add from my side:

Prepare for data loss. you can easily soft-brick device by disabling the wrong package. There is no way to undo this other than factory reset then. So be careful with that, and always do a backup beforehand.

This free open source tool is a little assistant to perform the adb commands more comfortable
https://github.com/0x192/universal-android-debloater